# Can I practice capistrano on my pc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am studying ruby on rails, but I am stopped in the chapter of deploying with capistrano,

I would like to know if I can do practice with capistrano on only my pc with windows 7?

I dont know well what is deploying, seems to be things about to use multiple servers on diferent places, so, can I practice on only a pc?(my pc with windows 7)

I would like if you have any tutorial or idea about this?

Comment: ruby installer for windows will give you the binaries you need. deploying is for multiple purposes be it servers or locations or an easy way to push code to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get micro instance on amazon for free for 1 year, and then you can practice not with only deploying, but also testing your applications in productions environment.
Also you can install other system into virtualpc(or similar) make proper routing to inside, and then after you configure environment, you could try to deploy. However that will not be easy

Answer (score 1):

Is **only my pc with windows 7** going to be valid if you have a Linux on a virtual machine?

If yes -  You can set up Virtual machine with [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) described in [Virtual Machines with Vagrant](http://railscasts.com/episodes/292-virtual-machines-with-vagrant) railscast. Install one of many [operating systems](http://www.vagrantbox.es/) available and start deploying to your new "virtual server" with capistrano.